# Encrypting data to be decrypted later

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, stripe-payments

I'm creating a method to calculated the price of upgrading a subscription package using stripe. Stripe has a feature built in and produces a proration price calculated at the time the request is made known as the value "proration_date".

If the client agrees on the price the user can purchase it at the shown price assuming I pass the "proration_date" along with the next request.

All these requests are done on the backend server and due to limitations the "proration_date" cannot be stored within a database meaning I need to give it to the client to hold.

To resolve this I would like to pass an encrypted token to the client which will hold the proration_date. Then on the payment request I would take the encypted token and decrypt it on my server.

I have tried and tested the code from 
[here](https://gist.github.com/vlucas/2bd40f62d20c1d49237a109d491974eb) and it appears to work. The base of the code is also shown.

This is method of encryption safe enough for my task?

```
function encrypt(text) {
 let iv = crypto.randomBytes(IV_LENGTH);
 let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', Buffer.from(ENCRYPTION_KEY), iv);
 let encrypted = cipher.update(text);

 encrypted = Buffer.concat([encrypted, cipher.final()]);

 return iv.toString('hex') + ':' + encrypted.toString('hex');
}

function decrypt(text) {
 let textParts = text.split(':');
 let iv = Buffer.from(textParts.shift(), 'hex');
 let encryptedText = Buffer.from(textParts.join(':'), 'hex');
 let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', Buffer.from(ENCRYPTION_KEY), iv);
 let decrypted = decipher.update(encryptedText);

 decrypted = Buffer.concat([decrypted, decipher.final()]);

 return decrypted.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the crypto module as intended. However, there are easy ways to break the AES in CBC mode, see for example http://cryptopals.com/sets/2/challenges/16 or http://cryptopals.com/sets/3/challenges/17. The former attack alters the plain text via the cipher text and the latter demonstrates how cipher text can be decrypted without the key.

The lesson is that confidentiality is only one aspect of cryptography; you also want data integrity. That is, you want to detect if an incoming piece of client data has been tampered with.

May I suggest looking at the this lecture to learn about message authentication codes (MACs): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DiLPn_ldAAQ. The textbook by the lecturer Christof Paar is also very accessible.

Comment: Would it be wiser to use GCM rather than CBC?

Comment: @Jack, yes, absolutely. Being an AEAD cipher, GCM gives you confidentiality, integrity, and (optionally) authenticity.